# Visual Basic quiz 1 questions is always wrong no matter what

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

To make it short, I have a database with questions, possible answers and good answers. I take 10 randoms questions from the database to create a multiple answer quiz in vb.net. My problem is that the Question with the ID_Question 7 is never right. Everything works for the other questions.
This is my database
[image: Relationships]
Sorry for censorship this information is not supposed to be shared
[image: Possible Answer]
[image: Questions]

This is my code use for this part(Code might not be needed, it might just be a problem in access)

This is my variables

```
'Variables for connection to database
Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Public dr As OleDbDataReader
Public dr2 As OleDbDataReader
Public dr3 As OleDbDataReader

   'Array of RadioButtons
    Dim RadioArray1() As RadioButton = {Q1a, Q1b, Q1c, Q1d, Q1e}
    Dim RadioArray2() As RadioButton = {Q2a, Q2b, Q2c, Q2d, Q2e}
    Dim RadioArray3() As RadioButton = {Q3a, Q3b, Q3c, Q3d, Q3e}
    Dim RadioArray4() As RadioButton = {Q4a, Q4b, Q4c, Q4d, Q4e}
    Dim RadioArray5() As RadioButton = {Q5a, Q5b, Q5c, Q5d, Q5e}
    Dim RadioArray6() As RadioButton = {Q6a, Q6b, Q6c, Q6d, Q6e}
    Dim RadioArray7() As RadioButton = {Q7a, Q7b, Q7c, Q7d, Q7e}
    Dim RadioArray8() As RadioButton = {Q8a, Q8b, Q8c, Q8d, Q8e}
    Dim RadioArray9() As RadioButton = {Q9a, Q9b, Q9c, Q9d, Q9e}
    Dim RadioArray10() As RadioButton = {Q10a, Q10b, Q10c, Q10d, Q10e}
```

When the Form load

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles   Me.Load
    'Set up connection to databse, change path depending on location
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dataFile = "Data Source=F:\Quiz\Programs\UNZipped\questions.mdb;Jet         OLEDB:Database Password=magic;"

    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    'Open connection
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim str As String
    Dim str2 As String
    Dim str3 As String
    'Select 10 random questions
    str = "SELECT TOP 10 ID_Question, Question From Questions ORDER BY Rnd(-(100000*ID_Question)*Time())"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


    Dim idArray(9) As Integer
    Dim QuestionArray(9) As String
    Dim LabelArray() As Label = {Label3, Label4, Label5, Label6, Label7, _
                                 Label8, Label9, Label10, Label11, Label12}

    'Dim RadioArray As List(Of RadioButton)



    Dim PossibleAnswerList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)


    Dim total As Integer = 0
    Dim cnt As Integer = 0
    While dr.Read()
        'Add id and question title into arrays
        idArray(cnt) = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("ID_Question"))
        QuestionArray(cnt) = dr("Question").ToString

        Dim num As Integer 'numbers of possible answers

        str2 = "SELECT Possible_Answer From PossibleAnswers Where ID_Question =" & idArray(cnt) & ""
        Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str2, myConnection)
        dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader

        str3 = "SELECT Count(Possible_Answer) From PossibleAnswers Where ID_Question =" & idArray(cnt) & ""
        Dim cmd3 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str3, myConnection)
        num = Convert.ToInt32(cmd3.ExecuteScalar)

        While dr2.Read()
            'Put all the possible answer of all the selected questions into a list
            PossibleAnswerList.Add(dr2("Possible_Answer").ToString)


        End While

        Select Case cnt

            Case 0 'Question 1 
                For i = 0 To num - 1
                    'Change text on Radio Button
                    RadioArray1(i).Text = PossibleAnswerList(total)
                    total = total + 1
                Next 
            Case 1 'Question 2
                For i = 0 To num - 1
                    RadioArray2(i).Text = PossibleAnswerList(total)
                    total = total + 1

                Next i
            Case 2 'Question 3
                For i = 0 To num - 1
                    RadioArray3(i).Text = PossibleAnswerList(total)
                    total = total + 1

                Next i
            Case 3 'Question 4
                For i = 0 To num - 1
                    RadioArray4(i).Text = PossibleAnswerList(total)
                    total = total + 1

                Next i
            Case 4 'Question 5
                For i = 0 To num - 1
                    RadioArray5(i).Text = PossibleAnswerList(total)
                    total = total + 1

                Next i
            Case 5 'Question 6
                For i = 0 To num - 1
                    RadioArray6(i).Text = PossibleAnswerList(total)
                    total = total + 1

                Next i
            Case 6 'Question 7
                For i = 0 To num - 1
                    RadioArray7(i).Text = PossibleAnswerList(total)
                    total = total + 1

                Next i
            Case 7 'Question 8
                For i = 0 To num - 1
                    RadioArray8(i).Text = PossibleAnswerList(total)
                    total = total + 1

                Next i
            Case 8 'Question 9
                For i = 0 To num - 1
                    RadioArray9(i).Text = PossibleAnswerList(total)
                    total = total + 1

                Next i
            Case 9 'Question 10
                For i = 0 To num - 1
                    RadioArray10(i).Text = PossibleAnswerList(total)
                    total = total + 1

                Next i
        End Select



        cnt += 1
    End While
    'Put the Questions text on the Label(runs 10 times)
    For i = 0 To QuestionArray.Length - 1
        LabelArray(i).Text = QuestionArray(i)

    Next i







    myConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

When submit is clicked

```
Private Sub ButtonSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonSubmit.Click

            Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection

                        Dim cmdOLEDB As New OleDbCommand

                        Dim cnnOLEDB2 As New OleDbConnection

                        Dim cmdOLEDB2 As New OleDbCommand

              Dim strConnectionString2 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = F:\Quiz\Programs\UNZipped\questions.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=magic;"
                        cnnOLEDB2.ConnectionString = strConnectionString2
                        'Declares a variable that counts the number of correct answers
                        Dim score As Short = 0
                        'Repeat this part 10 times for every different questions
            For i = 0 To RadioArray1.Length - 1
                            'Find which button is selected
                            If RadioArray1(i).Checked = True Then

                                'Set up connection to databse, change path depending on location
                                provider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
                                dataFile = "Data Source=F:\Quiz\Programs\UNZipped\questions.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=magic;"

                                connString = provider & dataFile
                                myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
                                'Open connection
                                myConnection.Open()

                                Dim str4 As String
                                Dim good As Int16

                                'Check if answer is right
                                str4 = "SELECT Good_Answer From PossibleAnswers where Possible_Answer='" & RadioArray1(i).Text & "'"
                                Dim cmd4 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str4, myConnection)
                                good = Convert.ToInt16(cmd4.ExecuteScalar)
End sub
```

Note: the last part is repeated 10 times to verify all 10 questions I just did not want to past to much code
Thank you

Comment: If your question 7 is always wrong, that means you've screwed up its index. Either in the assignment of its values, or in the comparison of the user's answer to the correct answer. So check the comparison code, and make sure you are comparing the user's answer for question 7 to the correct answer for question 7. If that is correct, check the assignments.

Comment: There is no comparison for the question 7 since the questions are chose randomly. Sometime the question is not there and when it's there it's always at a different spot

Comment: Is it possible that you have two _possible_answer_ with the same text? Your code search a match in the table using a string and not limiting the search to the relative question id. If two answers in different questions have the same text you could match the wrong one

Comment: This is very possible let me try to change it

Comment: Seems likes @Steve is right since it looks like the same answer can be found in question 6

Comment: @Steve You are right that was the problem I never tough of that, is there any way I easily fix that without changing the Possible_Answer

Comment: Sorry I had to refresh the page to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code searches a match in the `Possible_Answers` table using a string and it is not limiting the search to the current ID_Question.

If the table contains two records with the same answer text, it is highly probable that that query matches an answer intendend for a different question.

So the fix is relatively easy. When you query for the `good_answer` you need to add a WHERE condition also for the ID_Question....

```
str4 = "SELECT Good_Answer From PossibleAnswers " & _
       "where Possible_Answer='" & RadioArray1(i).Text & "' " & _
       "AND ID_Question = ?????"
```

Now the problem is just how to resolve the `ID_Question` when you are inside the button to submit the answer. This could be solved setting the Tag property of your Radiobutton array with the ID of the question.

```
Form_Load
.... 
   While dr.Read()
      'Add id and question title into arrays
      idArray(cnt) = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("ID_Question"))
      .....
      Select Case cnt
        Case 0 'Question 1 
            For i = 0 To num - 1
                'Change text on Radio Button
                RadioArray1(i).Text = PossibleAnswerList(total)
                RadioArray1(i).Tag = idArray(cnt)
                total = total + 1
            Next 
      ....
```

Now the final query could be rewritten using the Tag property

```
str4 = "SELECT Good_Answer From PossibleAnswers " & _
       "where Possible_Answer='" & RadioArray1(i).Text & "' " & _
       "AND ID_Question = " & RadioArray1(i).Tag
```

A final note. I have followed your style in writing this answer. But I should really warn you that concatenating strings to build command text is considered [the GOTO of Database Programming](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). You should never use this method. Use always a parameterized query approach to avoid Sql Injection and parsing problems